# How to use awk to print all lines whose third column value equals "0" instead of 0?

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I got a csv file has following format:

```
"hWcYw",1,"1","5HleiJXMsFkGEsr8Jqr3Ug",1
"hWcYw",1,"1","rCDlYd2WHJuiT05sYGxaVA",2
"m1oKE",1,"0","5HleiJXMsFkGEsr8Jqr3Ug",1
"1oKE0",1,"0","rCDlYd2WHJuiT05sYGxaVA",2
```

I want to get lines whose third column value is "0" notice that it is "0" with quotes not 0.

i tried

```
awk '$3 == 0' file.csv
awk '$3 == "0"' file.csv
```

but doesn't work. Any ideas? Thx ahead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -F"," '$3 == "\"0\""' file.csv
```

Without specifying the `FS` ( field separator ) the default is for awk to use white spaces, so the first problem with your attempt is that you only have one field.  Here, I'm using the `-F","` to specify the `FS` value from the command line.  Second, you just need to escape the double quotes as double quoting can be used to make valid awk regular expression strings for pattern matching.

You could also use a different format for the pattern match where you wouldn't need to escape the double quotes you want to match on:

```
awk -F"," '$3 ~ /"0"/' file.csv
```

Comment: +1: Though you might want to index the second variant. `awk -F"," '$3 ~ /^"0"$/' file` is probably more appropriate. IMHO, OP should just go with the first variant as it is clear and concise.

Comment: @jaypal - good point.  That better represents the `==` from the original.

Answer (score -1):

perl version:

```
$ perl -F, -lane   'print $_ if $F[2]=~/^"0"/' example.txt
"m1oKE",1,"0","5HleiJXMsFkGEsr8Jqr3Ug",1
"1oKE0",1,"0","rCDlYd2WHJuiT05sYGxaVA",2
```